# I need to -match a string that does NOT end with a specific set of characters (file extension)

Tags: regex, powershell

For an Exchange Online rule I'm trying to create a regular expression in PowerShell that matches (`-match`) any case that does NOT end with '.pdf'. Sadly I'm not that experienced yet with regular expressions. I'm using the following regex testing site to test.

http://regexstorm.net/tester

It seems to match the output you would get from PowerShell regex.

I have already tried the following: `.?[^\.pdf]$`.

This is what I get for output:

- `"test.txt" -match '.?[^\.pdf]$'` → True (this is what I want)
- `"test.docx -match '.?[^\.pdf]$'` → True (this is what I want)
- `"test.pdf.txt -match '.?[^\.pdf]$'`→ True (this is what I want)
- `"test.pdf" -match '.?[^\.pdf]$'` → False (this is what I want)

It starts to fail with the following examples:

- `"test.pdd" -match '.?[^\.pdf]$'` → False (this is NOT what I want)
- `"test.pdx" -match '.?[^\.pdf]$'` → False (this is NOT what I want)

I have also tried many things along the lines of: `'.?(\.[^pP][^dD][^fF])$'`, but I'm experiencing similar results.

Comment: The expression `"test.pdx" -match '.?[^\.pdf]$'` should evaluate to `True`, since `x` is neither `.` nor `p` nor `d` nor `f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reject matches that end with `.pdf` only, you can use this regex,

```
^(?!.*\.pdf$).*$
```

Which has a negative look ahead `(?!.*\.pdf$)` which rejects the match if string ends with `.pdf`

Here are the results of your commands,

```
PS C:\Users\user> "test.txt" -match '^(?!.*\.pdf$).*$'
True
PS C:\Users\user> "test.docx" -match '^(?!.*\.pdf$).*$'
True
PS C:\Users\user> "test.pdf.txt" -match '^(?!.*\.pdf$).*$'
True
PS C:\Users\user> "test.pdf" -match '^(?!.*\.pdf$).*$'
False
PS C:\Users\user> "test.pdd" -match '^(?!.*\.pdf$).*$'
True
PS C:\Users\user> "test.pdx" -match '^(?!.*\.pdf$).*$'
True
```

Your usage of negated character `[^.pdf]` only works for negating certain characters in a string and is not able to reject a sequence of characters like `pdf` for which you need to use negative look ahead the way I have used.

And `.?` means any character zero or once which is not the correct thing you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to do this is by using the `-notmatch` operator instead of `-match`. This allows you to simply write

```
$s -notmatch '\.pdf$'
```

Alternatively you could also use `-notlike` with wildcards:

```
$s -notlike '*.pdf'
```

Comment: Another alternative would be `-not $s.EndsWith('.pdf')`.